# How to clear a timer in setInterval function with on click trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, slideshow, setinterval

I've wrote a code:

```
 var timer = 0;   

$('.tour-slider').on('click', 'li a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.slider').hide();
    var sliderHref = $(this).attr('href');
    $(sliderHref).fadeIn();
    if(sliderHref == '#slider-1'){
        anim1.pause();
        anim2.pause();
        anim3.pause();
        anim1.start();
    }else if(sliderHref == '#slider-2'){
        anim1.pause();
        anim2.pause();
        anim3.pause();
        anim2.start();  
    }else if(sliderHref == '#slider-3'){
        anim1.pause();
        anim2.pause();
        anim3.pause();
        anim3.start();
    }
});



function slideshow(){
$('#slider-1').siblings().hide();
anim1.start();
timer = setInterval(function(){
    $('.slider:visible .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');

    $('.helper').first().removeClass('helper');
    if (!$('#slider-3').hasClass('helper')) {
        $('#slider-1, #slider-2, #slider-3').addClass('helper');
        $('#slider-1 .active').find('a').trigger('click');
        $('#slider-3').hide();
    }
}, 10000);

}
```

As you can see this is basic slideshow in infinity loop created with setInterval.

But now, I have to add some feature - if user click on 'a' element, then setInterval timer should restart.

Right now, slides change (#slider-1, #slider-2, #slider-3) in each 10sec. But when user click in another 'a' for example after 4sec, then slider will change, and change once again automaticaly after 6sec.

Now:
(#slider-1 show up > user click at 'a' after 4sec > #slider-2 show up > after 6 sec #slider-3 show up )

Want:
(#slider-1 show up > user click at 'a' after 4sec > #slider-2 show up > after 10sec #slider-3 show up)

I know, I have to use clearInterval, yes? But I dont know how to use it in my case.

HTML markup:

```
            <div id="slider-1" class="slider helper">

                <div id="animation-1">

                </div> <!-- end animation-1 -->

            <div class="tour-slider-content">

                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#slider-1"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slider-2"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#slider-3"></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div> <!-- end slider content class -->

            </div> <!-- end slider 1 -->
            <div id="slider-2" class="slider helper">
                <div id="animation-2">   

                </div> <!-- end animation-2 -->

                <div class="tour-slider-content">

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#slider-1"></a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#slider-2"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#slider-3"></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div> <!-- end slider content class -->

            </div> <!-- end slider 2 -->

            <div id="slider-3" class="slider helper">

                <div id="animation-3">

                </div> <!-- end animation 3 -->

                <div class="tour-slider-content">


                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#slider-1"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#slider-2"></a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#slider-3"></a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div> <!-- end slider content class -->

            </div> <!-- end slider 3 -->

        </div> <!-- end yout slider -->
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Cheers!

Comment: `clearInterval(timer)`

Comment: Did you try using clearInterval like this? `clearInterval(timer)`

Comment: yes, I've tried to paste clearInterval(timer) at the bottom of every 'if' statement in the click event but I think there is could be a problem with scope.. 
Should I try with pasting my 'click' event function into 'slideshow()' function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your function into a variable (give it a name) and remove and recall the setInterval everytime you need it:

```
timer = setInterval(do_slide, 10000);

...

function do_slide(){
    $('.slider:visible .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    $('.helper').first().removeClass('helper');
    if (!$('#slider-3').hasClass('helper')) {
        $('#slider-1, #slider-2, #slider-3').addClass('helper');
        $('#slider-1 .active').find('a').trigger('click');
        $('#slider-3').hide();
    }
}
```

Then just call these lines on click event:

```
if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(do_slide, 10000);
```